# Should I regroup all my Apis in one Api management

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

We have multiple Apis in our company.
I am working on a software for my company that will use 3 Apis only used by this software so we would like to use Azure Api management as a single point of access.

The question is:

- Should we create an Api management for this software for this 3 Apis only and in the future create other Api management if needed.
- Or should we create one and only one api management and any new or existing Api would go in this Api management (We could end with hundreds of API)?

With the First option, we limit the risk to these 3 apis but the cost would be higher.
In the second, there is the risk of single point of failure, imagine you do something wrong all Apis could be impacted. The price could be lower.

What do you think ?

Comment: api management is designed so you only need one api management at the enterprise level .... saying that you probably need an api management per environment or something like that

Answer (score 0):

> Should we create an Api management for this software for this 3 Apis only and in the future create other Api management if needed.

> Or should we create one and only one api management and any new or  existing Api would go in this Api management (We could end with hundreds of API)?

You can create an Api Management only for your required 3 api's  by using API aggregation concept.

And in the future if you want, you can create a new Api Management or you can also add other api's to the existing APIM.

> With the First option, we limit the risk to these 3 apis but the cost would be higher. In the second, there is the risk of single point of failure, imagine you do something wrong all Apis could be impacted. The price could be lower.

Yes, the basic cost would be applicable but there will be no latency while accessing the api's and are also secured when using APIM.